# How to convert aware Datetime field from UTC to local

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework, python-datetime, django-serializer

I have a DB that stores aware `Datetime` values. So for example a `Datetime` field in the DB can have the value `2015-11-06 12:22:39.160983+01`.

When an api call happens that requests the records that contains that value the response used to be like that `2015-11-06T11:22:39.160983Z`.

I then added

```
    timeStart = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

to the model serializer, which subclasses the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` class, and now the response is like that `2015-11-06 11:22:39.160983`.

What I want is to be able to translate the value back to the original local time. Meaning that I want the response to look like that `2015-11-06 12:22:39.160983`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting (perhaps temporarily) the timezone?

Comment: How can I do that? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You realize that you're going to have some inconsistencies in your date times in particular when going from summer time to winter time or the other way ?

Comment: General advice would be to leave the client to the conversion.

Comment: I cannot quite find a problematic example right now but you are probably right that this is not a good approach. Despite that I would like to be able to do that just for making the testing procedure a little bit easier.

Comment: I would agree with Linovia.  Only handle UTC on the server in all your server code and convert to local time zone on client.  Convert back to UTC before sending to server.  If it is a web client, javascript handles UTC <-> local time zone very easily.

Comment: yes, I see it clearer now that I have a better overview. Thanks a lot!